# Filter buttons on the main tag synonyms page do not work in IE7

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface, tag-synonyms

I've just spotted that, on the main tag synonyms [page](https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms), the fitler buttons do not work for me. I'm currently at work using IE7, which I suspect might be the issue, but cannot currently test in another browser.

I can get to the relevant pages via a little bit of URL tweaking:

```
https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=all
https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=active
https://superuser.com/tags/synonyms?tab=newest&filter=suggested
etc
```

Can anyone else confirm if this is a problem?

#### Side question:

Does StackExchange offically support IE7?
If not, then obviously I won't bother reporting any potential issues in the future.

Comment: It kind of works, you just need ninja skills to hit the top left corner. Ill see if I can fix it. making ie happy is very hard.

Comment: @waffles Ah ha, yes, there is a tiny selectable strip across the top of each button. I'll leave you to try and work some magic upon it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to have been completed.